# DataTrigger with Converter never gets hit

Tags: wpf, binding, datatrigger

In my application I'm overriding a DevExpress SimpleButton ControlTemplate in order to make it work with animations.

In the template I'm using a DataTrigger and a converter to check whether a value is not null and act accordingly.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dx:SimpleButton}"
                 x:Key="{dxt:ButtonThemeKey ResourceKey=ButtonControlTemplate}">
  ...
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding GlyphAlignment, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}"
                 Value="False">
      ...
    </DataTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I've set a breakpoint in my IsNullConverter but it never gets hit. I've tried TemplateBinding, Binding with RelativeSource set as Self, as well as TemplatedParent, none of it did anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Download `Snoop` as it is so useful to find wrong bindings ( and more :P ) https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf  - Don't know if we can paste these kind of links here so if we can't let me know and I'll delete this -

Comment: Did you try `Binding="{Binding GlyphAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}}`"?

Comment: It should actually be `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`

Comment: Yes, I tried both. `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` and `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`. I have snoop but it doesn't show any triggers.

Comment: Have you try Mode="TwoWay" with the binding?

Comment: @Frenchy What should that be good for?

Comment: @Clemens sorry for my english, following the binding and the type of converter, i have to use the mode="TwoWays" to have binding successfull .

Comment: @Frenchy You only need a TwoWay Binding when the source property should be updated on a change of the target property. This never happens with a DataTrigger.

Comment: @clemens, ok i understand.. thanks